What's the best naming convention for a digital library?
I am trying to organize my entire digital library; not just my novels, but RPG manuals, as well as some monographs. I recently started using Calibre (excellent so far), but I am struggling to find a cohesive naming convention for my books when listing them elsewhere, like in Google Drive.
Currently, I have been using several separate naming conventions.
Novels: Obviously, this is the default way books are often listing.

"[Title] by [Author]"

Game Manuals: This one can be quite cumbersome as the titles of campaign books can get to be rather long.

"[System] - [Title] [Edition]"

Monographs: These titles can also get rather long because of the subject matter being part of the title.

"[Publisher] - [Title] by [Author]"

Does anyone have any suggestions of what may be better, or a style guide of some kind?

If this is about filenames, then are you ruling out arranging them into folders/directories?

Partly about filenames and partly trying to come up with a universal system that is flexible enough for a variety of material types.
